# How to capture output of curl piped with grep into a variable in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I realise there are quite a few posts that show how to capture output of curl or grep, but haven't been able to find any post where I can capture the value of a group in the grep's regular expression.

I need to capture output of the following command in a variable inside a shell script.

I am working on API calls of Qlik tool.  The way the APIs work, is that you first have to call the login operation, which returns a session key and then use this session key in the subsequent API calls, like this

https://help.qlik.com/en-US/enterprise-manager/November2021/Content/EnterpriseManager/EnterpriseManager_APIGuide/CurlAPI/api_login.htm

```
cURL example
Active Directory request
curl -i -k --header "Authorization: Basic cWFAcWE6cWE=" https://computer.network.net/attunityenterprisemanager/api/v1/login

Response
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Content-Length: 0

Content-Type: text/html

Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0

EnterpriseManager.APISessionID: J3cKzWIbi_w6Fr1G-tO03Q

Date: Mon, 26 Dec 2016 17:02:01 GMT
```

And then use the `EnterpriseManager.APISessionID`

https://help.qlik.com/en-US/enterprise-manager/November2021/Content/EnterpriseManager/EnterpriseManager_APIGuide/CurlAPI/api_aem_getserver.htm

So, I am trying to get this `EnterpriseManager.APISessionID` value in a variable, so I can use it in the script to call other operations.

If I run the below command on the command line it prints the value on the terminal,

```
curl -i -k --header "Authorization: Basic mybase64idpwvalue" https://qlik-qem-dev.abc.com/attunityenterprisemanager/api/v1/login | grep '(EnterpriseManager.APISessionID: )(.*)' | echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
```

This is the output on command line

```
eu_3qrEWJFAz_4hL7bOIvA
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
```

but if I put it in a .sh file and execute it, then the variable value is empty

```
API_SESSION_ID=$(curl -i -k --header "Authorization: Basic mybase64idpwvalue" https://qlik-qem-dev.abc.com/attunityenterprisemanager/api/v1/login | grep 'EnterpriseManager.APISessionID: ')
API_SESSION_ID2=$(curl -i -k --header "Authorization: Basic mybase64idpwvalue" https://qlik-qem-dev.abc.com/attunityenterprisemanager/api/v1/login | grep '(EnterpriseManager.APISessionID: )(.*)')
#API_SESSION_ID=$(curl -i -k --header "Authorization: Basic mybase64idpwvalue" https://qlik-qem-dev.abc.com/attunityenterprisemanager/api/v1/login) | grep '(EnterpriseManager.APISessionID: )(.*)' |  echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
echo "API_SESSION_ID : ${API_SESSION_ID}"
echo "API_SESSION_ID2 : ${API_SESSION_ID2}"
```

I tried some other combinations of the command in the script, but am unable to capture the value in a variable.  It is always empty

How can I get that populated?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I don't know where `eu_3qrEWJFAz_4hL7bOIvA` comes from in your example. I'll assume you meant `J3cKzWIbi_w6Fr1G-tO03Q`.

Second, your command line output doesn't make sense, unless you played around with the shell and some global state remains. When I run it, I get a empty output, which is what I expect.

Third, `BASH_REMATCH` is a bash variable that captures the result of regex matching from bash operators (`[[ string =~ regex ]]`). It's not aware of grep, perl, sed, or any other programs using regex.
That's why when I run your command I get no output - `BASH_REMATCH` is empty.

Last, your grep expression uses unquoted parentheses, and you didn't pass `-E`, so it looks for parentheses in the text, and it wouldn't find them. So even if `BATCH_REMATCH` was aware of `grep`, `grep` would still return an empty result.

All that said, `sed` does support capture:

```
API_SESSION_ID="$( \
    curl -i -k \
        --header "Authorization: Basic mybase64idpwvalue" \
        https://qlik-qem-dev.abc.com/attunityenterprisemanager/api/v1/login \
        | sed -n 's/\(EnterpriseManager.APISessionID: \)\(.*\)/\2/p' \
)"
echo "API_SESSION_ID : ${API_SESSION_ID}"
```

That `\2` represents the second capture group. But you don't actually need the first:

```
API_SESSION_ID="$( \
    curl -i -k \
        --header "Authorization: Basic mybase64idpwvalue" \
        https://qlik-qem-dev.abc.com/attunityenterprisemanager/api/v1/login \
        | sed -n 's/EnterpriseManager.APISessionID: \(.*\)/\1/p' \
)"
echo "API_SESSION_ID : ${API_SESSION_ID}"
```

Comment: Thanks.  What I was saying is that when I run the command and pipe to grep and get the second group, from terminal, it prints the expected value on terminal.  But if I try to scriptise  that command and assign the output value to a variable, then the variable prints empty.  I realise my way of coding was wrong, and that is why this question.  The two options you have above, both are working in a script

Answer (score 0):

`BASH_REMATCH` isn't related to `grep`. It must be called after regex matching.

GNU grep (perl positive look behind):

```
echo "$example_header" |
grep -Po '(?<=^EnterpriseManager\.APISessionID: ).*'
```

Pure bash:

```
[[ $example_header =~ (^|$'\n')(EnterpriseManager\.APISessionID: )([^$'\n']*) ]]
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
```

Both print:

```
J3cKzWIbi_w6Fr1G-tO03Q
```

For input:

```
example_header=\
'Response
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Content-Length: 0

Content-Type: text/html

Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0

EnterpriseManager.APISessionID: J3cKzWIbi_w6Fr1G-tO03Q

Date: Mon, 26 Dec 2016 17:02:01 GMT'

# Or: example_header=$(curl -i -k --header "Authorization: Basic cWFAcWE6cWE=" https://computer.network.net/attunityenterprisemanager/api/v1/login)
```

Don't forget to escape `.` and to match the start of the line (to avoid matching `NotEnterpriseManager...`).

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, when command is run, the session id value changes, so the difference.  When I run the first GNU grep (perl positive look behind): with -Po, I get `grep: invalid option -- P`.  Also what I meant was when I run the commands `curl -i -k --header "Authorization: Basic mybase64idpwvalue" https://qlik-qem-dev.abc.com/attunityenterprisemanager/api/v1/login | grep '(EnterpriseManager.APISessionID: )(.*)' | echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"` together on command line, I get expected output, but when I tried to do that in a script, I get blank value. I must be doing wrong when putting in script

Comment: The Pure bash approach works.  The character limit had reached, so couldn't put that in first comment

Comment: @adbdkb You don't have GNU grep (which provides `-P`). I recommend sed instead: `sed -n 's/^EnterpriseManager\.APISessionID:[[:space:]]\+//p'`. You should also consider piping the curl output through `tr -d '\r'` to remove carriage returns.

Comment: This answer is also valid.  I accepted the other one because it was a single command example instead of two steps